# Using Fragments Causes Crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have worked towards creating the simplest project I can which cause me problem. I originally thought this was a maps problem until I realized it was probably a general (*support library*?) fragments problem. (I have tried running this code on my SGII v4.1.2)

Java code:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MSMap extends FragmentActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_msmap);
  }
}
```

XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >
    <fragment        
        android:id="@+id/themap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Above give this error with "error inflating":

> 03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MSMap}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error
>   inflating class fragment 03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
>   03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>   03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
>   03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-09 12:06:56.850:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-09 12:06:56.850:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>   03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-09 12:06:56.850:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(891): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>   03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
>   03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   com.example.testapp.MSMap.onCreate(MSMap.java:23) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>   03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
>   03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):    ... 11 more 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null 03-09 12:06:56.850:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:354) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:491) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369) 03-09
>   12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
>   03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
>   03-09 12:06:56.850: E/AndroidRuntime(891):    ... 21 more

Is there somehow a mismatch between code and XML?

- I have tried have my code extend activity and fragmentactivity?
- The XML contains a relativelayout surrounding the fragment? Is that a
  problem somehow?

Under all circumstances, I have tried all example I could think and/or Google my way to. All resulting in the same error.

**Note:** I have android-support-v4.jar in "References Libraries" and "Android Dependencies" and "Libs" in my project.

Answer (score 3):

Finally i got answer for your question

A Fragment works much like an activity, in that you need a Java class file to go with it. you cannot create a Fragment just by creating a fragment layout - you need a class for your fragment:

Create a layout XML and an Activity subclass for your activity
Create a layout XML and a Fragment subclass for your fragment
Tie the two together in your Activity layout XML (or using FragmentTransaction if you want to do it in Java code)
If you haven't already done so, read, re-read and digest everything on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

There's a lot there, but Fragments are an essential part of Android apps now so it's required reading. The good news is that the basics of fragments is pretty simple.

So you need to have a class like this

```
<fragment
       class="com.exercise.FragmentTest.MyFragment"
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't sepcify the name for your Fragment , you should provide your fragment class in name attribute for your fragment

like code below :

```
<fragment        
    android:name="com.yourPackageName.YourFragmentClass" 
    android:id="@+id/themap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
```

Comment: In the original map demos, they use this class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment". (From what I have read, "class" and "name" are more or less interchangable) However, I got same problem using that. (Exact same error.) I guess I should try find a simple complete fragments example and see if I still get an error.

Comment: @Tom , for using fragment you have to define a class for your fragment that extends a listfragment ... so you have to define your fragment class in your fragment layout.and in your fragment class you define it's own layout in onCreateView() function.it's not as hard as you may think

Comment: Thanks. Just for reference, this was one of multiple examples I found using maps/support-fragments that gave the same error I get: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-google-map-v2-part-1.html (I suppose the Google maps class extends listfragment or similar which is why it should work. Maybe it is two different causes giving me the same error. I am trying to pinpoint where the error happens, so I can research that further. But I will try create a fragment "demo" in my own project which I will use to replace google maps with. That way I can diagnose which of the two issues is culprit)